# CSS Incompatible: Nivo Slider Pushes Elements of Page Awry

Tags: css, html, nivo-slider

Task: Drop in Nivo Slider where Pic is

Result: RSS Feed, Search and bottom half of page way off

Question: How to fix CSS to align RSS Feed, Search and bottom of page

Here is the site with a pic where the Nivo Slider goes:
http://scottjaxon.com/devsite/index.html

Here is the 43rd time I've attempted to get it aligned:
http://scottjaxon.com/devsite/testnivo43.html

CSS for the site:

```
/* home */


#wrapper #user1 #feahome {
min-height: 341px;
height: auto !important;
height: 341px;
}
#wrapper #user1 #feahome #containerflash {
width: 960px;
height: 325px;
overflow: visible;
border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#wrapper #user1 #feahome #rsshome {
float: left;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 440px;
height: 20px;
margin-bottom: 6px;
padding: 6px 20px 0px 20px;
border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#wrapper #user1 #feahome #searchhome {
float: left;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 22px;
margin-top: 8px;
padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

Comment: your website is missing some css that the other website has. I suggest you use either Firefox with [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome with the inbuilt developer tools to see what css is missing in your website. [Here is a video](https://getfirebug.com/video/Intro2FB.htm) that shows you how to use firebug.

Comment: Do you not just need to drop all of the content under the Nivo Slider into the wrapper div?

Comment: http://scottjaxon.com/devsite/testnivo45.html

Comment: http://scottjaxon.com/devsite/testnivo45.html -thanx effectica - firebug Yes! now the rss/search box is way to big -imma make the slider bigger at the bottom and  . . . probably squeeze the box a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem is that your wrapper div is closed too early. Remove the div from where I marked it at the top and add it at the bottom just before your body tag. See screenshot:

[image: wrapper div problem]

Comment: Awesum! thnx! I'm such a newbie @ CSS n i'm coming at web design from graphic design and painting. I designed a lot when tables were all the rage, then painted for a while, now it's all CSS. Tables were so much easier! I don't get why their not used anymore, sure they have their limitations but ease of use was visual not all math-like.